# htaccess 301 redirect — remove a path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to do this htaccess 301 redirect, but I am stuck.

What I want is to remove a string in the URL, the path is:

```
/index.php/images/forum_icons/
```

I want the redirect it so all pages that may get that path in the URL will be removed. -- Thanks in advance.

**FROM:**

```
/index.php/images/forum_icons/feed.php?f=6
```

**TO:**

```
/feed.php?f=6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} f=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^index.php/images/forum_icons/feed.php$ /feed.php?f=%1 [NE,R,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I think you are close.  I get an 404 error, but look at the end how it's repeated: "feed.php?f=6&f=6"

Comment: Not getting a 404 error, but the end of the target URL shows this: "/feed.php?f=6%3f&f=6"

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed it!  Looks good now.  I swear I would have never figured this out.  I search a lot of tutes and other help sites, but nothing fit what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: A quick question?  Is it necessary to enter the entire URL of the site for the target?  example: http://www.example.com/feed.php?f=%1 [NE,R,L,NC]  -- even though it's redirecting the local site and not a remote site?